# How to "browserify" a node.js module into a browser importable ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, parceljs

I first thought this would be trivial, but after digging into it, I can't find a way to do this. Is this impossible?

For example, I would like to take any node.js package and compile it like this:

```
import { method } from "SomeLibrary";
export const api = method
```

and maybe run webpack or parcel

```
parcel build index.js
```

and was hoping it would result in a standalone JavaScript, which I can call from a `<script type='module'>`, like this:

```
<script type="module">
import { api } from "SomeModule.min.js";
api()
</script>
```

But I can't find a way to make this work. Is something like this impossible?

Comment: Take a look https://medium.com/code-oil/webpack-javascript-bundling-for-both-front-end-and-back-end-b95f1b429810.

Comment: @MikiBelavista this is not related to what I'm asking. I already know how to build JS, I even know how to build node modules in a "standalone" mode so it can be dropped in as a single variable. Here I'm specifically asking about building the module so that it can be imported like an ES module inside a `<script type="module">`

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens?

Comment: That should work. I'm not familiar with parcel, but rollup certainly does support single-file builds. Please tell us what the problem (error message) is when you try to use *SomeModule.min.js*.

Comment: "*take any node.js package*" - that of course is not possible, if the package depends on some native nodejs modules. So it always depends.